# Animating two constraints simultaneously - Order matters?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a nested view that I animate out of the frame completely on a certain action. To do this, I update the constants for the constraints in an animation block.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
    self.categoriesTableViewConstraintToBottom.constant = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    self.categoriesTableViewConstraintToTop.constant = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    [self.view layoutSubviews];
}, completion: nil];
```

Basically the two constraints just tie it to the top and bottom of the parent view (which is full screen). Obviously I can't change one of these constraints without changing the other, otherwise the layout isn't satisfiable.

The weird part here is I have to change these in the order I showed above. If I update the constants in the other order, it throws an 'satisfy' error.

So:

1. Why does the order matter?
2. Are we technically supposed to remove constraints while changing them if they will conflict until we update all the constraints? (Are they evaluated immediately for some reason instead of waiting for `layoutSubviews` or `layoutIfNeeded`?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're doing here. What is categoriesTableViewConstraintToBottom doing? Is that a constraint from the bottom of the table view to the bottom of the superview? Does the table view have its height set to something?

Comment: So basically I have my view controller view. Inside of it I have a table view which takes up the full space (for good reason). I don't define the height of the tableView, instead it's height is determined by constraining its top and bottom to the top and bottom of the superview (so that it adjusts for iPhone 4 or 5). At a certain point, I want to animate the tableView out of the frame. So I animate the top and bottom constraints.

Comment: The views are actually updated as soon as the constraints change. If you step through the code, you may see that the warnings are spit out as soon as the constraints are changed -- not at layoutIfNeeded. I believe the best way to update the constraints (when animating) is to use the visual format to adjust the leading/width/trailing or top/height/bottom all at the same time. If we use references to the user generated constraints then we introduce order...coupling.

Comment: That wouldn't make sense. You don't want to add new constraints, you want to adjust the constants on the existing ones. It also doesn't explain why order would matter. If they are evaluated immediately, then updating either constraint to something that makes the other one impossible it should throw an error. Instead it only does it in one direction.

Comment: Intuitively, I agree, but experimentation indicates something else. I wouldn't add constraints -- I would just adjust them simultaneously to minimize the likelihood of order-coupling. Have you tried stepping through the code? Do the warnings popup at layoutIfNeeded for you?

Comment: I believe the answer for order-requirements lies in minimum-required size :)

Comment: I am adjusting them simultaneously, but you appear to be correct that they evaluate immediately... sometimes... in a certain order. So weird. No warnings pop up in the 'correct' order, even on layoutIfNeeded.

Comment: Well adjusting them simultaneously would look like this: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(0)-[categoriesTableView]-(0)-|"... Perhaps we should ask an iOS engineer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25982/discussion-between-bob-spryn-and-rey-gonzales)

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the constants outside the animation block?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't matter. It happens regardless.